# Do you lose anything when you die in Watch Dogs?

Tags: watch-dogs

Is there any downside from dying apart from the obvious progress you might lose if you are currently on a mission?

Do you lose

- money?
- reputation?
- equipment?
- experience?
- anything else?

It just seems strange to me that you can die outside of a mission without any negative effects.

Comment: Your dignity. Ubisoft games are easy.

Answer (score 9):

When you die the world resets a bit and it does not always remember certain things. Overall I would say just that there are no negative effects to your character but it can be very inconvenient.

For example, you will not always reset to where you were. This can cause things you had before in the environment to no longer be available. I can not express how many missions I have had be made harder simply because it reset me to a location not only without the vehicle I had with me, but without any vehicles nearby at all.

That does appear to be the extent of the changes though, strictly just the environment getting reset. Your money, reputation, player equipment and experience are all still intact.

Answer (score 2):

There don't seem to be absolutely any downsides to dying in free roam and losing progress if you're on a mission.